# How do I change an html cell's color on click, if the table is generated dynamically?

Tags: javascript

```js
function drawTable() {

  var table = document.getElementById("myTable");

  var input = prompt("Insert height (in number of cells)");
  var a = +input;
  var input2 = prompt("Insert width (in number of cells)");
  var b = +input2;

  for (var i = 0; i < a; i++) {
    var row = table.insertRow(i);
    for (var j = 0; j < b; j++) {

      var cell = row.insertCell(j);
    };
  };
};
```

I can't for the life of me figure out how to add a onClick event that would change the color of a cell. Do I create a new function in JavaScript and add an onClick event to the table element? That's what I did, but it doesn't seem to work.

```js
  function changeColor() {
      var td = document.getElementsById("myTable").getElementsByTagName("td");
      td.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (var j = 0; j < b; j++) {

  var cell = row.insertCell(j);
  cell.addEventListener("click", changeColor.bind(cell), false);
};

function changeColor(e) {
      this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

Should do the trick. Every cell gets an onclick handler set in the `for` loop. Bind passes the reference of the cell to the `changeColor` function. The function can address the cell by using `this`.

Comment: No need to bind the cell; the target is available as part of the `event` data.

Comment: @Mathletics, True. I was thinking over an alternative too. But this one is the simplest version that will always work. If the cell contains elements the event.target will not refer to the cell, but to the element clicked upon. You need to iterate over the parent nodes to find the correct element. But Always +1 to avoid binding like this.

Answer (score 1):

For some situations, the answer suggested by [Mouser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4364303/mouser) work well. But if consider a situation taking your example of table creation based on number of rows and columns, then adding eventlistener to **each cell** doesn't sound a good approach. Suppose at initial user requested for 10X10 table. At that moment, 
eventlistener is added to each cell.

But what if at some later point of time, more rows/columns are added dynamically. In that situation, only thing you will left with is to add event listeners.

Better approach is to understand the term

> Event Delegation

In this approach, you add event listener to parent and just listen to event bubbled up(default behavior) by the child elements.In that case you dont have to be worry about dynamically created cells and adding event listeners to those.

You can take a look on working sample with Event Delegation approach on your code at below link:

http://jsfiddle.net/zL690Ljb/1/

```
function drawTable() {

 var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
 table.addEventListener("click", changeColor);

 var input = prompt("Insert height (in number of cells)");
 var a = +input;
 var input2 = prompt("Insert width (in number of cells)");
 var b = +input2;

 for (var i = 0; i < a; i++) {
    var row = table.insertRow(i);
    for (var j = 0; j < b; j++) {

    var cell = row.insertCell(j);
  //cell.addEventListener("click", changeColor.bind(cell), false);
};
};
};

function changeColor(event) {
    if (event.target && event.target.tagName && (!event.target.tagName.match(/table|th|tr|tbody|thead/i)) )
    {
      var element = event.target;
      while (element && element.parentElement)
      {
          if(element.tagName=='TD'){
               element.style.backgroundColor = "red";
               break;
          }
          else
          {
             element = element.parentElement;
          }
      }
    }
}

drawTable();
```

I hope [Mouser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4364303/mouser) will agree on this. Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't you check that the `tagName === 'TD'` (the cell) instead of _not_ the table? Otherwise yes, event delegation is the right approach.

Comment: True!..Just for working sample i did, but anyways i am editing it..thanks!

Comment: @Rakesh_Kumar Mouser agrees, but has one issue with this. What if somebody clicks upon an element inside the cell. The cell's background won't change now, because the target is the element and not the cell. However the parent cell is clicked and should turn red.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the for you can add the onclick event for each cell:

```
for (var i = 0; i < a; i++) {
    var row = table.insertRow(i);
    for (var j = 0; j < b; j++) {
      var cell = row.insertCell(j);
      cell.onclick = function(){
        changeColor(this);  
      }
    };
};
```

Then the changeColor will be as following:

```
function changeColor(cell) {
    cell.style.backgroundColor = "red";

}
```